# Permanent SEO-safe 301 Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS Effecting Aliases

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, hosting, plesk

I am using Plesk Onyx Version 17.5.3 Update #24. I have `Domain->Hosting Settings->Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS` checked.

I'm looking for a way to force HTTPS on the primary domain in the Plesk Panel without forcing HTTPS on the aliases.

Alias http://alias.tld for the primary domain https://domain.tld gets redirected to https://alias.tld and a SSL warning about insecure connection appears, instead of redirecting to https://domain.tld which does not get a warning.

If I make an exception for the warning on the alias, it then properly redirects to the primary domain.

What's happening:

1. http://alias.tld redirects to https://alias.tld
2. https://alias.tld redirects to https://domain.tld

What I'm expecting:

1. http://alias.tld redirects to http://domain.tld
2. http://domain.tld redirects to https://domain.tld

I can even accept:

1. http://alias.tld redirects to https://domain.tld

Here are some workarounds that I've found:

- I can uncheck this box and add `.htaccess` rules on the primary domain to first redirect the domain and then force the HTTPS. *(This would not work since we have non-developers enabling SSL via Plesk and they cannot configure a `.htaccess` file)*
- I can redirect the domain at the registrar. *(This would not work as clients change their password frequently and we don't always have access to their domain registrar)*
- I can create the alias as a `Domain` instead of a `Domain Alias` and use it's own Web service to redirect to the primary domain. *(This would not work as the service plan in Plesk does not allow the subscription to have multiple domains, only multiple domain aliases)*

*Please note that we are using a single domain SSL provided for free from the hosting company and we are not able to obtain a multi-domain SSL for this purpose.*

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve is currently not possible via Plesk panel.

You could, however, use Let's Encrypt (Plesk extension) to create a SSL certificate for your alias domain.
If you are unable to do that, your hosting company should be able to do it for you.

Comment: I've succeeded in doing so using the first work-around method listed in my question, so it is possible. Would you kindly explain how to bind an SSL certificate to a `Domain Alias`? I see no such methods in [Plesk Onyx Documentation](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/). As I've mentioned in the question, we cannot obtain a multi-domain SSL. As for `Let's Encrypt`, I personally use it on my own server. Unfortunately `Let's Encrypt` does not issue organization or extended validation certificates which is unacceptable for some clients.

Comment: I wanted to say that there is no way in Plesk panel to do what you desire (you would have to change some configuration files / templates for that).
You could use Let's Encrypt to issue a SSL certificate (DV) for your alias domains, that way redirect would work without any issues. There is another way, instead of creating a domain alias, you could create a new domain with document root pointing to main domain's document root. That should let you install any certificate you want the normal way (in Plesk) and having that domain show the content of your main domain. Haven't tried that one though.

Comment: I got really excited seeing that `Let's Encrypt` allows [SSL Certificates on Domain Alias](https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4450777-ssl-certificate-for-domain-alias). However, it replaces the current SSL to do so. We cannot replace the SSL on the primary domain.